# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement') for reading html element in jasmine for angular

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

below case is failing have same scenario in other place its passing

```
  it('login lables', () => {
    const terms = fixture.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
    expect(terms.querySelector('#LoginUsernameLabel')?.textContent).toContain("User ID");
  });
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-12 row align-items-center hb-login-container" id="Login">
  <section class="col-10 offset-1 col-sm-8 offset-sm-2 col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-lg-4 offset-lg-4 hb-login-box"
    id="HBLoginBoxSection">
    <h1 class="mb-4" id="HBLoginHeading">Login</h1>
    <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="col-12 p-0 hb-login-form" id="HBLoginForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="LoginUsername" class="hb-form-label" id="LoginUsernameLabel" [ngClass]="{
            'hb-field-error':
              !!f.username.invalid &&
              (!!f.username.dirty || !!f.username.touched)
          }">User ID</label>
```

getting error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement')`

should pass test case

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that something is going wrong while setting up your test's environment, but I can't be 100% sure of that since you haven't shared how your tests are set up